# Bind to ItemsSource and SelectedValue of a ListView inside of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-controls, itemssource

My goal is to reuse a `ListView` and a couple of other controls that are inside of a `UserControl` I designed.

For the sake of brevity, imagine that I have a `Person` class like this, and a list of its instances.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

My `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="ReusableListView.MainWindow"
        ...
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid>        
        <local:UCListView Margin="8"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _personList = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList
    {
        get { return _personList; }
        set { _personList = value; OnPropertyChanged("PersonList"); }
    }

    private Person _selectedPerson = null;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set { _selectedPerson = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonList = GetPeople();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person() { Name = "Jane", City = "NYC" },
            new Person() { Name = "John", City = "LA" }
        };
        return list;
    }
}
```

I want to display the `Name` property of `Person` as individual items in my `ListView` inside the `UserControl`, and then to the right of it, I want to display the selected person's `City` property. So my `UserControl` look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReusableListView.UCListView"
             ...
             x:Name="MyListViewUC"
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="580">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="256" Margin="8"
                  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListViewUC}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Width="Auto" Margin="8" Background="Pink"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="8" Background="PaleGreen"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the `UserControl` code behind:

```
public partial class UCListView : UserControl
{
    public UCListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(UCListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

The above code is stitched together from most examples I saw online including SO. Here are my problems and questions.

1. When I run this, nothing is displayed in the `UserControl` list. What seems to be the problem?
2. How do I bind the `SelectedPerson` property to the `UserContro.` so it knows how to display the correct `City` based on selection?

Comment: Doesn't look to me like you're assigning your MainWindow's `DataContext` anywhere.

Comment: @jsanalytics, in my actual program I do use a ViewModel. This was just to simply and post an easier MCVE.

Comment: NEVER EVER rely on the items selected by `ListView` or `ComboBox` always go for the bound properties! This sort of behaviour drives `WinForms`. Good job you didn't use MvvM tag here cause there is NONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that you missed to set the DataContext of the Window like

```
DataContext = this;
```

you should consider to derive your control directly from ListView or the simpler ListBox, because then you would get direct access to all its useful properties.

The difference to a UserControl is that the XAML is in a default Style in the ResourceDictionary `Themes/Generic.xaml`, which is automatically generated when you add a custom control to a WPF project.

The control's code, where you change the base class from Control to ListBox:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    static MyListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyListBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyListBox)));
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:...">

    <Style TargetType="local:MyListBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyListBox">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You would use your MyListBox like any other ListBox:

```
<local:MyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 SelectedValuePath="City">
```

---

If you're not intending to have additional properties in your derived ListBox, you could as well not derive a control at all, and just assign the ControlTemplate to a ListBox when you declare it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyListBoxTemplate">
        ...
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...

<ListBox Template="{StaticResource MyListBoxTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         SelectedValuePath="City">
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, thanks! I want to use a `ListView` because this is a simplified MCVE, but in reality I need to show a lot of stuff in one row and `ListView` is the better fit. So does this mean we can't quite use things like `ListView` or `ListBox` inside of a `UserControl`?

Comment: You can of course, but unless you don't want to bind properties of the inner elements directly to a view model (in the DataContext inherited from the UserControl's parent element), you would have to replicate all necessary ListView properties like ItemsSource, SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, DisplayMemberPath, ItemTemplate and perhaps a few more.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of that as well?

Comment: You already have that in the other answer. However, you should not set the ListView's DataContext, but just write `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. And it is also not necessary to use `IEnumerable<Person>` as property type. `IEnumerable` is sufficient. I have edited the answer accordingly. In general, reuse the property types from ItemsControl/ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

So this one got me interested. I messed around with the code a bit and I found that in order to make this work I had to set the DataContext for MainWindow as Mark suggested. So in the MainWindow constructor, you can just put

```
DataContext = this;
```

I also found that there was an issue with the way you had your dependency property setup. You have it set as an object. If you set it to IEnumerable it will work. I am sure that there is a more generic way to do this, however, this should get you headed down the right road. The problem is that ItemsSource is not able to use an Object. It needs IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UCListView));
```

One last thing you will need to do is either create a dependency object to pass through the DisplayMemberPath or set it statically in your user control. I just set it statically but you will probably want to create a dependency property to pass it through so that it can be dynamic.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="256" Margin="8"
          x:Name="listView"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListViewUC}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"/>
```

You will have to remove the ItemTemplate. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks. Yes silly me about not setting the data source. However, this doesn't answer my second question, about how to set the Selected Item. Still, thank you.